# Error during checked the box with condition

Tags: reactjs

Code doesnot have any error but I cant Able to load the check boxes. Iam using nested loop to cheeck the condition if tag.id== taged.id then i need to  make itchecked.What to do?

```
<div className="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        TAG
      </label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <div className="checkbox">
          {tate.tags.map(
            (tag) =>
              hiding.hide &&
              form.tags.map((taged) => (
                <label>
                  <input
                    name="tag[]"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={tag.id}
                    onChange={handlecheck}
                    checked={tag.id == taged.id ? true : false}
                  />
                  namnemnma {tag.Tag_name}
                </label>
              ))
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell that what's `hiding.hide` contains? It might be falsy value and that would result in not rendering checkboxes? Or `form.tags` arr could have been empty? Did you checked thos values ?

Comment: in consone  components I have hiding.hide=true, form.tags have value in array

Comment: Can you show your `handleCheck` method in this code snippet as well?

Comment: const  handlecheck = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);

 let newArray=[...form.tag, event.target.value];
    if (form.tag.includes(event.target.value)) {
      newArray = newArray.filter(bhim => bhim !== event.target.value);
    }
setForm({...form,tag:newArray});
  }